# using a public static class in a 'Project' with defined namespaces

Tags: c#, asp.net, static

In the past, I have not really used namespaces, but in this project I am using SourceSafe which requires a project, which puts everything in namespaces...

In the past, I have just been able to make a public static class in the App_Code folder and access it frorm anywhere in my application, but now I cant seem to do that.

For example, my default.aspx.cs looks like this:

```
namespace Personnel_Database
{
    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              utils.someFunction();//this does not work
```

and my utils.cs class looks like this:

```
namespace Personnel_Database.App_Code
{
    public static class utils
    {
```

How can I have it so I can call **util.someMethod()** inside of my default?  Am I wrong assuming it is a namespace problem?  I just want **utils.cs** to be available globally inside namespace **Personnel_Database**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you include the namespace with a using directive:

```
using Personnel_Database.App_Code;
// now you can use everything that is inside the Personnel_Database.App_Code namespace
namespace Personnel_Database
{
  ...
```

Or you use the fully quallified name of the utils class (including its namespace), e.g:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Personnel_Database.App_Code.utils.someFunction();
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add:

```
 using Personnel_Database.App_Code;
```

to the top of your code-behind file.  If you need access to it in the markup you can import it using:

```
 <%@ Import Namespace="Personnel_Database.App_Code" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a using statement in the Personnel_Database Personnel_Database class file, i.e.

```
using Personnel_Database.App_Code;
```

Google/MSDN for the using statement.

Answer (score 0):

I was mistaken, if I insteada make the Utils class:

```
namespace Personnel_Database
{
    public static class utils    
    {
```

It does work, buut does not show in intellisense, how can I get it to do that?

Comment: If you go this route -- and I don't necessarily recommend it since namespaces do add value in ordering your code -- you might also want to change the default namespace in your project properties so that new classes created in the project get your preferred namespace as the default.